# Keyboard shortkey for AutoHotKey

Tags: batch-file, autohotkey

I know how to set keyboard shortcut for single key.

for example : <kbd>windows</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> will open that command.

```
#z::Run www.autohotkey.com
```

is there a way if user presses <kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> twice to execute different command?

```
zz::Run www.google.com
```

Thanks

Comment: So you want a hotstring, such as `::zz::Run www.google.com`?

Comment: Yes, I have many shortcuts to set, thats why I need to use if user type z once, it will go to Yahoo.com, if zz twice to google.com thanks

Comment: This would ruin user's life! He will never be able to press z, if you map it to Yahoo.com. or zz to google.com. If you think, that zz is not a common word, imagine, if he has it in password? I know, there are ways for workaround, like `z<space><backspace>z`, or copy paste zz from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks but I found better way. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found better way,

it won't be same key but we can use multiple key press.

```
1::
Input Key, L1

if Key=z
    {
        ;your code
}
if Key=u
    {
        ;your code
}
```